# Having trouble linking google calendar api with my website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-calendar-api, appointment

I created an OAuth 2.0 Client ID for my wordpress website, I am using the WordPress Appointment Booking Plugin but when I select 'Connect with Google' I get this error message:

Authorization Error
Error 403: access_denied
The developer hasn’t given you access to this app.

I am logged into the same account for everything

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution,
I had to go into the OAuth consent screen and add myself as a test user